# executing pages built in 1.1 and 2.0 framework in same website

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, .net-2.0, .net-1.1

I am having an application which is built in 1.1 framework.This application is now rebuilt in 2.0 framework but due to some reason we have to use some of the pages of 1.1 framework. So for this we are executing both the applications simultaneously and n carrying out the work using querystrings. So my question can we include pages made in 1.1 and 2.0 framework in one website , if not then please suggest me any other alternative because me method is not that secure... waiting for response ....

Comment: What's the reason for retaining the older 1.1 pages? Bottom line is that you will need to have it all 2.0...

Answer (score 0):

You can not run two different "main versions" of asp.net together under the same name, like the 1.1 and 2.0

The main reasons each one is connected to a pool, and the pool is running by the IIS, and each pool have only version that can be run, and iis can handle one pool per site. And you can not run two servers at the same port (80).

**The only way to run is to separate the url name, or the port** and have eg:

`www.site.com` and `www1.site.com` and setup two different pools to run a 2 totally separate sites, and some how you connect the links from one to the other, or use iframe and include some parts of the one to the other.

The better way is to port the version 1.1 to version 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can run the web site under .NET 2, and some of its directories under .NET 1.1. Note that the web site should run in a .NET 2 application pool, while the .NET 1.1 directories run in a .NET 1.1 application pool.

As far as I remember, it is not possible to run the site in .NET 1.1 and some directories in .NET 2.

To save yourself from drowning in troubles, you should fully migrate to .NET 2 in this case.

Even when .NET 4 comes, side by side execution is still difficult (as you can see from this article, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a99txfy5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).