# Replacing old DLL with new DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net

My client lost the source code of their web application and wanted to make few small changes to it. I used RedGate's .Net Reflector to extract the source code from the DLL. Using the class files generated I was able to make changes at the desired place and re-generate the DLL. The application pool used by the application is "default" with version 1.1 and I think the application was also created using .Net framework 1.1, but I used visual studio 2008 to open the project and create the new DLL. also the old DLL had some version number. My question is: since the application is already online, will replacing the new DLL create any problem? Since the time frame given to us to replace the DLL is very small as the application can not stay offline for long, I want to make sure that everything goes fine. Am I following the right way? Or, do I have to create the new DLL using the same framework(1.1)? What else do I need to do to keep the application running smooth without any problem. Kindly excuse me for this lame question but this is the first time I am in this sort of scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While re-building your DLL, you need to ensure two things:

[1] The target framework of the project is the same as the one where you will be deploying it. You may check the currently targeted framework version from project->properties. If your live server has only 1.1, then so should be your target set in the project file.

[2] Need to ensure that all dependencies are met. You can see all dependencies from the References in solution explorer.

Comment: Thanks Prahlad. I understood but we don't have framework 1.1. Is there a workaround to do it using visual Studio 2008

Comment: The important thing is that even if you build with VS2008, your can't install it on live if your live has only FW 1.1. Do you know what frameworks are installed on live ? If it has 2.0 or above installed, then yes, you may use VS2008 to build

Comment: Then yes, you can certainly build using VS2008. Just ensure that the target framework in your project properties is also set to 2.0. Apart from that, you will also need to ensure that all dependencies are present on your live server too as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: OK. I have made the necessary configurations. And, I don't have to change the application pool version. Currently it is 1.1. This DLL created targeting 2.0 will work then? As there are 18 other application running using the default application pool with version 1.1, so obviously I can't change that.

Comment: Yes, both your 1.1 DLLs and the newly built 2.0 DLL can coexist on the same pool. But just ensure that the application pool itself is 2.0 and not 1.1, because you can run 1.1 web apps in 2.0 pool but not vice versa!. See this SO link to know more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987638/executing-pages-built-in-1-1-and-2-0-framework-in-same-website

Answer (score 1):

If there's anything else which references this DLL, you'll likely need to decompile/recompile that as well as the public key will more than likely change if you deconstruct the source. You should be safe to just copy it over, which will trigger a restart of the app pool.

Comment: Thanks Echilon. References are well taken care of. THE only concern is regarding framework. We don't have framework 1.1. Is there a workaround to do it using visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 0):

To limit the issues you encounter you need to build the assembly against the 1.1 framework. Then, during the down window:

1. Stop the application pool.
2. Replace the assembly.
3. Restart the application pool.

Comment: Thanks Michael for this quick response. Just a couple of questions. 1) I do not have .Net Framework 1.1, is there a workaround if I can do the same with Visual Studio 2008? 2) What with the version number of previous assembly?

Comment: @user1640256, I have to say multi-targeting only goes back to 2.0 in Visual Studio 2008, you really need to find a way to get a copy of Visual Studio 2003. And the version number, it should have decompiled the `AssemblyInfo.cs` which would have contained the version number, so I would just leave that alone.

Comment: @user1640256, no problem. You're in a tough spot, and I've been there, I'm sorry to hear about it.

Comment: Yes Michael. I am indeed in a tough spot. But that's the way we work. Don't we?

Comment: @user1640256, yeah, but I'm getting a little old to keep working up hill ... :D